# nativescript worker ts want service variable

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, nativescript, web-worker

I am creating native app using nativescript. I have situation that handle functionality in background (like Thread in JAVA). I had research on google and i got nativescript worker, but in worker.ts how to get service variable?

sync.component.ts

```
export class SyncComponent implements OnInit{
    worker: any;
    constructor(private router: Router, private sqliteService: SqliteService) {
        this.worker = new Worker("../../shared/worker/sync.worker");
        this.worker.onmessage = (msg) =>{
            console.log('data ',msg.data);
        }
        this.worker.onerror = (err) => {
            console.log("Sync Components");
            console.dir(err);
            this.worker.terminate();
        }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }

    handleSyncNow() {
         this.worker.postMessage({msg: 'hi'});
    }
}
```

sync.worker.ts

```
require("globals");
var http = required('http');

onmessage = (msg)=> {

    console.log('in Worker onmessage: ',msg.data.msg);
    //var sqliteService = ;//How to get sqliteService variable Of SqliteService(ts) class
    //global.postMessage('hey this is from worker');

    handleSync();
};

onerror = (err) => {
    console.log(err);
}

function handleSync() {
     this.http.get(Config.apiUrl).map(response => response.json())
        .do(data => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.message);
        });
}
```

sqlite.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SqliteService {
    handleSyncData() {
        //Wrote required code
    }
}
```

my question : how to call `handleSyncData()` function in `sqlite.service.ts` From `sync.worker.ts`'s `onmessage()` function?

Comment: You can only pass serializable objects to the worker service, there is no way to pass your SQL lite service to the worker process. you may be able to import the Service since it's just a class and new it up in the worker thread. that all depends on how that service works and what dependencies it has if any.

Comment: @theOriginalJosh ok if i import that class but how to create object of that class. there is no any constructor in worker thread, so where i can create class object?

Comment: you _may_ be able to do something like `const sqllite= new SqlliteService();` to new up the service inside the worker thread...

Comment: @theOriginalJosh i cant create new object of that class because i created constructor in SqliteService where i created other services object like `constructor(private service1: Service1, private service2: Service2, etc...) {}`. so how can i create new object of that class?

Comment: You can new up those new dependencies before creating your sql service. however depending on the structure of your project that may end up being a rabbit hole, so I'd say it's probably better off recreating the functionality of the SQL lite service for the worker. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share variables like that. `SqliteService` is an object that holds some internal handles and as such cannot be serialized.

You will need to create another instance in your worker and work with that.

Think about it like this, if this were Java application, sharing same object of SQL controller would lead to errors - every thread needs it's own database interface instance, which holds it's state for that thread.

Comment: i updated `sync.worker.ts` created `handleSync()` function that call backend API, after that changes `handleSyncNow()` function from `sync.component.ts` is not calling and there is no any exception. do you have any idea?

Comment: @AkashChavda That's a completely different problem than the one outlined in question. Ask another question about that.